# Which thread does a NSOperation get run on if executed manually using [NSOperation start]?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I want to execute an NSOperation synchronously on the currently executing thread. Can I just call [NSOperation start]? Does this always run in the currently executing thread?

An alternative is to just create an NSOperationQueue, add the operation then call waitUntilAllOperationsFinished selector.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can run synchronously on current queue (unless it's a queue that allows concurrent operations), can you? If you're on the main queue and ask it to do something synchronously (i.e. waiting for it), you can block the main queue. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `[NSOperation start]`, it will execute synchronously on the current thread. All the asynchronous work surrounding operations is handled by `NSOperationQueue`, but if you're calling `-start` yourself then you're bypassing all of that.

Of course, a particular `NSOperation` subclass may be implemented to spawn off an asynchronous task itself on another thread; that's entirely up to it. But an operation that's designed to execute synchronously in whatever thread the operation queue runs it in, will also execute synchronously in your thread if you call `-start`.

---

For example, the following code, when run:

```
NSOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"operation");
}];
[op start];
NSLog(@"complete");
```

prints:

```
operation
complete
```

Comment: do you have a reference anywhere that states this is the case? Specifically that it runs on the "current thread", I've seen elsewhere that it runs on the main thread and not the current thread

Comment: @aloo: Where did you see that? Because that is absolutely wrong. Anyway, the documentation states "The default implementation of this method updates the execution state of the operation and calls the receiver’s main method.". And `-main` is used for non-concurrent tasks, e.g. tasks that just run synchronously.

Comment: awesome thanks - saw that here: "If you call “start” on an instance of NSOperation, without adding it to a queue, the operation will run in the main loop." from: http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues